# Why are the two waves (or functions) interfering?

Tags: javascript

I was coding a function to plot graphs in JS. Here it goes:

```
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var prevx = 0;
var prevy = 0;
var zoom = 25;

function plot(func) {

    this.func = func;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.prevx = prevx;
    this.prevy = prevy;

    function draw() {

        c.beginPath();
        c.moveTo(this.prevx * zoom, this.prevy * zoom);
        c.lineTo(this.x * zoom, this.y * zoom);
        c.strokeStyle = '#fff';
        c.stroke();


        this.prevx = this.x;
        this.prevy = this.y;

        this.x += 0.1;
        this.y = func(this.x);

    }

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        draw();

    }

    animate();
}

plot(Math.sin);
plot(Math.cos);
// plot(Math.tan);
```

Why are the two functions interfering even if i am using **this** keyword?

There are already many similar questions on this website itself still i can't get my answer, hence i have asked here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm pretty sure all your `this` keywords in this code (except in the `c.lineTo(...)` etc calls) are actually pointing to the global object. So no wonder the properties are overwriting each other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use "this" keyword within a function, it refers to the function itself. Here you want it to refer to the "plot" function while you are inside the "draw" function. You can do that by creating a new variable within the "plot" function and use that. i.e. "that".

```
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var prevx = 0;
var prevy = 0;
var zoom = 25;

function plot(func) {
    var that = this;
    this.func = func;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.prevx = prevx;
    this.prevy = prevy;

    function draw() {

        c.beginPath();
        c.moveTo(that.prevx * zoom, that.prevy * zoom);
        c.lineTo(that.x * zoom, that.y * zoom);
        c.strokeStyle = '#fff';
        c.stroke();


        that.prevx = that.x;
        that.prevy = that.y;

        that.x += 0.1;
        that.y = func(that.x);

    }

    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
        draw();

    }

    animate();
}

plot(Math.sin);
plot(Math.cos);
```

You can do the same by using the "bind" method when you call a function. This would change the "this" keyword in that function to refer to the object passed.

```
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var prevx = 0;
var prevy = 0;
var zoom = 25;

function plot(func) {

    this.func = func;
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.prevx = prevx;
    this.prevy = prevy;

    this.draw = () => {

        c.beginPath();
        c.moveTo(this.prevx * zoom, this.prevy * zoom);
        c.lineTo(this.x * zoom, this.y * zoom);
        c.strokeStyle = '#fff';
        c.stroke();


        this.prevx = this.x;
        this.prevy = this.y;

        this.x += 0.1;
        this.y = func(this.x);

    }.bind(this)

    this.animate = () => {
        requestAnimationFrame(this.animate);
        this.draw();

    }.bind(this)

    this.animate();
}

plot(Math.sin);
plot(Math.cos);
```